# Where is the best place to relax after arriving in KUL

Tags: accommodation, hotels, kul

After 23 hours of traveling I will arrive in KL 30 december and want to stay on a quiet but nice place for new year's evening. I want to stay for some days but not in KL. Do anyone have some suggestions?

Comment: This question, as worded, is not suited for this site, because it is asking for opinions. If you want opinions of hotels, check a hotel booking site--most of them offer plenty of reviews and other ratings.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please have a read of the [help], as polling for suggestions is considered off-topic; there are too many possible answers.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "quiet but nice"?  Quiet five star city hotel in Putrajaya?  Quiet jungle hut?  Quiet beach resort?

Answer (score 1):

So your question is a bit vague, but I know where *I* would go if I landed in KL on December 30th and didn't want to tackle the Muddy Confluence yet -- I'd go to [Putrajaya](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Putrajaya), Malaysia's bizarre Pyongyang-meets-Dubai-meets-Las Vegas capital-to-be, halfway down the train line from KLIA to KL.

[image]
[image]
(pictures by me, c. 2006)

More specifically, I would stay at the [Shangri-La Putrajaya](http://www.shangri-la.com/kualalumpur/putrajayashangrila/), which is quiet and rather more than nice, all at a very reasonable price -- used to be around US$70/night back in the day, will be more now especially near NY but still won't break the bank.  Infinity edge pool, views over the surreal skyline of the city, decent restaurants that are only moderately overpriced, lots of pretty ladies in tight skirts and thigh-high slits gliding around, all you'd expect from an Asian 5-star hotel.

It's been a few years since I last visited and there are probably newer, shinier hotels there by now, but I'm pretty sure you won't be disappointed.  The only major catch with "PJ" is that getting around without a car is semi-impossible, but taxis are available, and this is the kind of hotel where just being there is the whole point.